# selenium xpath to pick list element that exactly matches the text

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a two list item in a list namely

"VxDev: InterAction Test Automation List"

"Anti - VxDev: InterAction Test Automation List"

I want to select "VxDev: InterAction Test Automation List". 
But the xpath

`Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//option[text()[contains(.,'" + listName + "')]]"));`

picks the "Anti - VxDev: InterAction Test Automation List".

```
<option value="8589934979">Anti - VxDev: InterAction Test Automation List&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
<option value="8589934864" selected="">VxDev: InterAction Test Automation List&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
```

Please let me know how to select the right list that matches the listName

Comment: <option value="8589934979">
          Anti - VxDev: InterAction Test Automation List
          &nbsp;&nbsp;</option>

<option value="8589934864" selected="">
          VxDev: InterAction Test Automation List
          &nbsp;&nbsp;</option>

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly set in the xpath the text of the other element should not be present:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//option[contains(text(), '" + listName + "') and not(contains(text(), 'Anti -'))]"));
```